# AMD64 misalignment of array in C: why no performance degradation?

Tags: c, arrays, alignment, x86-64

i tried to cause a performance degradation by misaligning an array in C. My machine has a 64 byte cache, thus i used a step size of 64 byte in the program, starting from the misaligned address. the results however, stayed the same as when using correctly aligned accesses. also using multiple arrays didn't change anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 10000000
#define DATATYPE long
#define ALIGNMENT __alignof__(DATATYPE)
#define CACHE_SIZE 64
#define STEP_SIZE (CACHE_SIZE / sizeof(DATATYPE))
#define NR_ARRAYS 20
#define ALIGNMENT_OFFSET 1

DATATYPE arr[N];

DATATYPE sum(DATATYPE **ptr, int size) {
    DATATYPE sum = 0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += STEP_SIZE) {
        for (j = 0; j < NR_ARRAYS; j++) {
            sum += ptr[j][i];   
        }
    }   
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    DATATYPE *arrs[20];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NR_ARRAYS; i++) {
        arrs[i] = (DATATYPE*)((long) malloc(N * sizeof(DATATYPE)) + ALIGNMENT_OFFSET);
    }

    long result = 0;
    clock_t tic = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        result += sum(arrs, N-1);
    }
    clock_t toc = clock();
    printf("result: %ld ", result);
    printf("elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

i have the following questions:

1. are the array accesses in the program really misaligned?
2. did i consider the main things that likely influence the performance in this program?
3. is it possible, that the performance is the same for an ALIGNMENT_OFFSET of 0 and 1, because of some "magic", that my CPU performs?

Comment: You are just measuring page fault cost in this code, they blow out the signal from the misalignment.  You have to warm up RAM and the cache first.  Simply execute the loop twice, the second time you should have something to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to perf (see https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) most of the time in your code is taken by the loop instructions (comparison + jump) associated with:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i += STEP_SIZE)


       │    DATATYPE sum(DATATYPE **ptr, int size) {                                        ▒
       │        DATATYPE sum = 0;                                                           ▒
       │        int i, j;                                                                   ▒
       │        for (i = 0; i < size; i += STEP_SIZE) {                                     ▒
       │            for (j = 0; j < NR_ARRAYS; j++) {                                       ▒
       │                sum += ptr[j][i];                                                   ▒
  2.83 │60:   mov    (%rdx),%rdi                                                            ▒
  4.37 │      add    $0x8,%rdx                                                              ▒
  5.50 │      add    (%rdi,%r8,1),%rcx                                                      ▒
       │                                                                                    ▒
       │    DATATYPE sum(DATATYPE **ptr, int size) {                                        ▒
       │        DATATYPE sum = 0;                                                           ▒
       │        int i, j;                                                                   ▒
       │        for (i = 0; i < size; i += STEP_SIZE) {                                     ▒
       │            for (j = 0; j < NR_ARRAYS; j++) {                                       ▒
 86.29 │      cmp    %r12,%rdx                                                              ▒
       │    ↑ jne    60                                                                     ▒
  0.10 │      add    $0x40,%r8                                                              ▒
```

As a consequence you don't see the influence of bad alignment.

Answer (score 1):

> are the array accesses in the program really misaligned?

Yes, they are, if `sizeof(DATATYPE)` is greater than 1.

> did i consider the main things that likely influence the performance in this program?

<s>No, you didn't. For example, 100 iterations is nothing. Write a loop of 100 million iterations and you will get a more realistic result.</s> Nevermind, I misread the code. The benchmark so far looks "fine" (apart from the UB), however, there may still be other factors to take in consideration.

> Is it possible, that the performance is the same for an `ALIGNMENT_OFFSET` of 0 and 1

Everything is possible, since your program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would the array be misaligned if `sizeof(DATATYPE)` is greater than 1? Sorry if a little off-topic, might also be useful to the OP.

Comment: @user9000 Why would it **not** be misaligned? Pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of `sizeof(type)` units, not in terms of bytes.

Comment: Right, makes sense, sorry for such dumb question.